# Amazon s3 Pre-signed URL restricted by IP address

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ip-address, pre-signed-url

The client app requests a presigned URL for S3. Currently we limit the time the URL is valid but would like to also restrict it to the client's IP address.

Is it possible to create a S3 presigned URL that is restricted to a specific IP address?

From what I can tell only CloudFront will let me do this.

Answer (score 24):

Yes!

First, it is worth explaining the concept of a Pre-Signed URL.

Objects in Amazon S3 are **private by default**. Therefore, if somebody tries to access it without providing credentials, access will be denied.

For example, this would not work for a private object:

```
https://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/foo.json
```

To grant **temporary access** to the object, a **Pre-signed URL** can be generated. It looks similar to:

```
https://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/x.json?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIVJQM12345CY3A3Q&Expires=1531965074&Signature=g7Jz%2B%2FYyqc%2FDeL1rzo7WM61RusM%3D
```

The URL says *"I am *this* particular Access Key and I authorize temporary access until *this* time and here is my calculated signature to prove it is me"*.

When the Pre-Signed URL is used, it **temporarily uses the permissions of the signing entity** to gain access to the object. This means that I can generate a valid pre-signed URL for an object that I am permitted to access, but the pre-signed URL will *not* work if I am not normally permitted to access the object.

Therefore, to "create a S3 presigned URL that is restricted to a specific IP address", you should:

- **Create an IAM entity** (eg IAM User) that has access to the object (or the whole bucket) with a IP address restriction, and
- **Use that entity** to generate the pre-signed URL

Here is a sample policy for the IAM User:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "IPAllow",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "54.22.33.44/32"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The result will be a pre-signed URL that works successfully to access the object, but is then rejected by S3 because the IP address restriction is not met. The user will receive an **Access Denied** message.

Comment: But what if we what to limit IP address dynamically to the specific end user making the request?

Comment: @openwonk Probably by programatically creating the user with ip restriction and generate signed url after switching users

Comment: @openwonk No, this is not a method for generating a pre-signed URL for a user's specific IP address. The intention with a pre-signed URL is that the time-limit will grant the user temporary access to the object. While that user could Tweet the URL to the world and other people would be able to access the object during that time period, the user could equally just distribute the file to people anyway. So, the assumption is that a time-limit is sufficient protection for most use-cases, without having to further limit the pre-signed URL to a specific IP address.

Comment: That was my understanding too. Thanks

Comment: @jbooker Pre-signed URLs do not have policies. They simply grant access based upon an existing user's permissions. Think of it like signing a cheque -- as the account owner, you are granting permission for the bearer of the cheque to withdraw money. The cheque does not contain the permission, it simply contains your authorization for access. However, it only grants access to _your_ account.

Comment: To clarify: My proposal does not require the app generating the presigned URL to be "in the same IP". Rather, the app generating the presigned URL merely needs to be using a set of credentials that has a policy that limits what it is allowed to access. The client using the presigned URL will be similarly limited when attempting to access the object. (When generating the presigned URL, the app can use a special set of credentials that has been limited, which might be different to the identity that the app uses for the rest of its operations.)

Comment: @jbooker Yes, I just tested it and it works fine for multiple IP addresses. To specify multiple IP addresses, use the format like shown in [Cloudflare IP Range Whitelist to S3 bucket through CloudFront : aws](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/bd8m8v/cloudflare_ip_range_whitelist_to_s3_bucket/). I created one user with S3 permissions for 3 IP addresses and created a presigned URL. It worked from those IP addresses, but not others.

Comment: Gotcha here worth mentioning: whitelisting at both user policy level and bucket policy level. :/

Comment: ?? No bucket policy is required for the above to work.

Comment: I meant to say, if you whitelist at user policy level and bucket policy level, you will have to maintain TWO sets of white lists. Minor GOTCHA

Comment: is it possible to use 'Temporary security credentials' (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp.html) for this purpose?  I'd like to be able to IP lock short lived urls to each of 3000 user's IPs - I recon I'd run out of IAM users if I had to create a new one each time, and then manage them.

Comment: @SimonH The method shown above could be used with temporary credentials, but the resulting pre-signed URL would only be valid while the temporary credentials are valid. The user of the pre-signed URL is effectively using the credentials that created the pre-signed URL, so they can do whatever those credentials can do, for as long as those credentials can do them (but limited by the expiry period that is requested during creation of the pre-signed URL).

Comment: @JohnRotenstein thankyou - I guess that the temporary credentials requested would be added to the IAM user used to create URL.  If one IAM user, and doing it a LOT, then each URL could be accessed by a number of IPs according to which credentials were still valid.  So this approach may be bad.  It would protect you from the URL being public access, but if a URL were leaked, the attacker simply needs to cause a different URL created within a certain period using thier IP, and the leaked URL would become valid for the attacker.  Food for thought.