# Create Amazon S3 Pre-signed URL restricted by VPN only access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, vpn, aws-amplify, pre-signed-url

I'm using AWS Amplify library Storage module to access S3 objects and can able to read/write objects in S3. If I'm not wrong Amplify Storage module uses Presigned URLs for GET and PUT.

Now I've a requirement to restrict S3 object access only through VPN. I presume the presigned URLs work over internet.

Please suggest a solution to restrict S3 object access only through VPN.

Comment: Can you whitelist the VPN IPs?
Then using some solution like that?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51407211/amazon-s3-pre-signed-url-restricted-by-ip-address